# Nested JqueryUI Tab(s) as Angular directive - Mismatching fragment identifier

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, jquery-ui-tabs

I try to create a **mastertab**. This mastertab holds n panels. Each panel contains a **subtab**, also with multiple panels. The tab ids of the subtabs are made unique dynamically. The construction renders as expected, but when I click on an inactive subtab panel, I get this error

> Uncaught Error: jQuery UI Tabs: Mismatching fragment identifier.

I made a **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7u4Ub/4/)**

The HTML to 'start' the mastertab

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div master-tab></div>
</div>
```

The mastertab directive

```
myApp.directive('masterTab', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        template: '<div id="mstrtab"><ul><li><a href="#master-tab1">Mst 1</a></li><li><a href="#master-tab2">Mst 2</a></li><li><a href="#master-tab3">Mst 3</a></li></ul><div id="master-tab1"><p>master panel 1<div sub-tab="Foo"></div></p></div><div id="master-tab2"><p>master panel 2<div sub-tab="BAR"></div></p></div><div id="master-tab3"><p>master panel 3</p></div></div>',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            element.tabs();
        }
    }
});
```

Notice I give subtabs a parameter:

```
<div sub-tab="BAR">
```

And here is the subtab directive:

```
myApp.directive('subTab', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: true,
        template: '<div id="subTab{{tabLetter}}"><ul><li><a href="#sub-tabs1{{tabLetter}}">SubTab1{{tabLetter}}</a></li><li><a href="#sub-tabs2{{tabLetter}}">SubTab2{{tabLetter}}</a></li><li><a href="#sub-tabs3{{tabLetter}}">SubTab3{{tabLetter}}</a></li></ul><div id="sub-tabs1{{tabLetter}}"><p>SubTab {{tabLetter}} 1</p></div><div id="sub-tabs2{{tabLetter}}"><p>SubTab {{tabLetter}} 2.</p></div><div id="sub-tabs3{{tabLetter}}"><p>SubTab {{tabLetter}} 3.</p></div></div>',

        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.tabLetter = attrs.subTab;
            console.log(attrs.subTab);
            element.tabs();
        }
    }
});
```

I think it has something to do with the rendering order in Angular, but I am not sure. Checking the rendered HTML source reveals that sometimes {{tabLetter}} might not be rendered, but in the presentation all seems OK. Also the underlying javascript objects seem to have the right and expected names...

Can anybody help me with this puzzle? How do I get this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `element.tabs()` plugin is initialized within the link function, the angular expression `subTab{{tabLetter}}` is not rendered yet.

To resolve this you can you use the $timeout service:

```
myApp.directive('subTab', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: true,
        template: '<div id="subTab{{tabLetter}}"><ul><li><a href="#sub-tabs1{{tabLetter}}">SubTab1{{tabLetter}}</a></li><li><a href="#sub-tabs2{{tabLetter}}">SubTab2{{tabLetter}}</a></li><li><a href="#sub-tabs3{{tabLetter}}">SubTab3{{tabLetter}}</a></li></ul><div id="sub-tabs1{{tabLetter}}"><p>SubTab {{tabLetter}} 1</p></div><div id="sub-tabs2{{tabLetter}}"><p>SubTab {{tabLetter}} 2.</p></div><div id="sub-tabs3{{tabLetter}}"><p>SubTab {{tabLetter}} 3.</p></div></div>',

        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.tabLetter = attrs.subTab;
            console.log(attrs.subTab);

            $timeout(function() {
                element.tabs();
            }, 0);
        }
    }
});
```

**[EDIT]**
The above solution works because it ensures that `.tabs` plugin initialization happens after browser rendering.

An alternative approach is to use $watch and provide it with a $watch handler. This solution also works because the $watch handler is called after the browser renders the view:

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.tabLetter = attrs.subTab;
    console.log(attrs.subTab);
    scope.$watch('tabLetter', function(newVal) {
        var val = newVal || null;  
        if (newVal) {
           element.tabs();
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: I read about the $timeout, but some comments say this is some kind of workaround. Anyway, for now I don't need this to be more fancy or political correct. @pixelbits It works like a charm. Thank you very much!